# middleware return a response of error but balance function is executing and app get crashed React js

Tags: node.js

am using middleware to check quantity before update if its zero it shows error otherwise it moved to main function to update it
My middle ware

```
exports.checkQuantity = (req, res, next) => {

     let myOprations = req.body.product.map(prd => {
          
               Product.findOne({_id: prd.productId}, (err, prDet) => {  
                    let inventory = prDet.inventory;
                    console.log(inventory);
                if(inventory === 0) {
                         console.log(inventory);
                    return res.status(422).json({"Message":"Please Check the stock!"});
              
                } else {
                    let avai = inventory - prd.quantity;
                    if(avai <= 0) {
                        return res.status(422).json({"Message":"Please Check the stock!"});
                        
                    }
                }
               })
         
     });
     next();
}
```

after sending response to my browser , the next() is working i think , it execute next function and get crashed

*** ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client ***
This is the error what i got it crashed the app and stop the server
Please help me to overcome this , Thanks in advance

Comment: I see you are using `map` but aren't making any transformation. In this case, you should use `forEach`... And the problem is that, if `product` is indeed an array, for every element you are trying to send a response. That's where the error come from. You could set a flag to indicate an error, use `break` to stop the iteration and then, outside the loop, return the response

Comment: i aready tried that ya , flag is not get updated , so only i set the response inside of map

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `product` that comes in the body of the request is indeed an array, you could try this:

```js
exports.checkQuantity = (req, res, next) => {

  let validStock = true;
  const products = req.body.product;
  
  for (prd of products) {
    Product.findOne({_id: prd.productId}, (err, prDet) => {  
      let inventory = Number(prDet.inventory);
      let avai = inventory - Number(prd.quantity);
      console.log("Inventory:", inventory, "Available:", avai);      

      if (inventory === 0 || avai <= 0) {
        validStock = false;               
      }  
    }
    if (!validStock) {
      break; // Breaks out of the loop
    }
  }
  
  // If the stock is not valid, send the error response
  if (!validStock) {
    return res.status(422).json({"Message":"Please Check the stock!"});
  }
  
  // If the stock is valid, call next()
  next();
}
```

But if `req.body.product` is not an array, it should work by simply removing the `for` loop.